# Unhandled exception error when trying to login with Sitecore CLI

Tags: sitecore-cli

I have this error when trying login to sitecore using CLI.

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'cdp.config.json' was not found and is not optional.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Telemetry.ContainerExtensions.AddSitecoreCdpTelemetryClient(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, String channel) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Telemetry\ContainerExtensions.cs:line 34
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.CliInvoker.Run(String[] args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli\CliInvoker.cs:line 118
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Tool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Tool\Program.cs:line 13
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Client.Cli.Tool.Program.<Main>(String[] args)`
```

this is the command

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority  xxxxxx xxxxxx --allow-write true
```

even when I ran simple sitecore command like "dotnet sitecore -h", I still get the above error but when I tried "dotnet sitecore --version" it shows the version. So it's already installed.

Sitecore cli version: 5.2.113

Have someone encounter this error before?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'cdp.config.json' was not found and is not optional.

Comment: @MarkCassidy do you know where to put the configuration file "cdp.config.json". Is it the root of the project folder?

I have tried the dotnet sitecore login command with the "--no-telemetry" flag but still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering seems related to the **Sitecore CLI not being able to find the 'cdp.config.json' configuration file (this is a mandatory one)**. This issue might be due to misconfiguration or missing files. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the problem **(note- this is not the perfect solution but this might help to troubleshoot the issue)**:

**Configuration File:**

Ensure that the 'cdp.config.json' file is present in the expected location. The configuration file might be missing or incorrectly named. You can create it manually if it doesn't exist.

**Configuration File Content:**

If the 'cdp.config.json' file exists, check its content for correctness. It should contain the necessary configuration settings, including authentication details.

Here's a basic example of what the 'cdp.config.json' file might look like:

```
{
  "Authority": "https://your-identity-server",
  "ClientId": "your-client-id",
  "ClientSecret": "your-client-secret",
  "SitecoreAuthority": "https://your-sitecore-instance",
  "SitecoreApiHost": "https://your-sitecore-instance/sitecore/api",
  "TelemetryChannel": "your-telemetry-channel"
}
```

**Telemetry Configuration:**

The error mentions telemetry. If you don't need telemetry, try running the command without it:

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority xxxxxx xxxxxx --allow-write true --no-telemetry
```

**Sitecore Support:**

If nothing works then I would suggest checking with the Sitecore Support Team.